# How to get gVim to respect the aero snap keyboard shortcuts, ie Win+Left, Win+Up, etc

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows

Is there a way to get gVim on Windows 10 to respond to the Windows aero "snap" shortcuts that move the window the left, right, maximize, minimize? Ie, `Win+Left`, `Win+Right`, `Win+Down`, `Win+Up`.

I assume that gVim is muting the behavior somehow and if I could "unmap" the right command that Windows would handle the rest? But things like

```
:mapclear <T-Left>
```

Don't seem to work. I'm not sure `<T-` is the right prefix...

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!